# lvalue required as left operand of assignment C++ compilation error

Tags: c++, compilation, lvalue

Im trying to build a minesweeper game and i keep getting a compiling error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment. only on these two lines:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

// ------------------------------------------------------
// class Cell
// represents one grid element in the Minesweeper game
// ------------------------------------------------------

class Cell {
public:
    Cell();
    void print();
    void peek();
    void unittest();
    void setMined(bool);
    bool getMined();
    void setAdj(int);
private:
    bool covered;
    bool marked;
    bool mined;
    int adjcount;
};


// ------------------------
// functions for class Cell
// ------------------------

Cell::Cell(){
    covered = true;
    marked = false;
    mined = false;
    adjcount = 0;
//  cout << "Creating a Cell" << endl;
}

void Cell::setAdj(int n){
    adjcount = n;
}

bool Cell::getMined(){
    return mined;
}

void Cell::setMined(bool b){
    mined = b;
}

void Cell::print(){
    if (marked) cout << " L ";
    else {
        if (covered) cout << " ? ";
        else{
            if (mined) cout << " @ ";
            else if (adjcount == 0) cout <<  " _ ";
            else cout << " " << adjcount << " ";
        }
    }  
}

void Cell::peek(){
    if (mined) cout << " @ ";
    else if (adjcount == 0) cout << " _ ";
    else cout << " " << adjcount << " ";
}

void Cell::unittest(){
    print(); cout << endl;

    covered = false;
    print(); cout << endl;

    adjcount = 4;
    print(); cout << endl;

    mined = true;
    print(); cout << endl;

    covered = true;
    print(); cout << endl;

    marked = true;
    print(); cout << endl;
}

// -------------------------------------
// class Board
// this class represents a 2 dimensional
// array of Cell objects for the game
// of minesweeper
//--------------------------------------

class Board{
public:
    Board();
    void print();
    void peek();
    void adjacencycount();
    void mixMined();
private:
    static const int rows = 5;
    static const int cols = 5;
    Cell cells [rows][cols];
    int mines;
};

// --------------------------
// functions for class Board
// --------------------------
Board::Board(){
    mines = 6;
        for(int i = 0; i < 1 ; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < mines; j++){
                cells[i][j].setMined(true);
            }
        }
}

void Board::mixMined(){
    int shuffle = 1000;
    for(int i = 0; i < shuffle; i++){
        int r1 = (rand()%rows);
        int c1 = (rand()%cols);
        int r2 = (rand()%rows);
        int c2 = (rand()%cols);
        if(r1 && c1 != r2 && c2){
            bool temp = cells[r1][c1].getMined();
            cells[r1][c1].getMined() = cells[r2][c2].getMined();
            cells[r2][c2].getMined() = temp;
        }
     }

}

void Board::adjacencycount(){ 

    for( int i = 0; i < rows; i++){      
        for( int j = 0; j < cols; j++){ 
            if(!cells[i][j].getMined()){
                int count = 0;
                    if (i-1 >= 0 && j-1 >= 0 && cells[i-1][j-1].getMined()) count++;
                    if (i-1 >= 0 && cells[i-1][j].getMined()) count++;
                    if (i-1 >= 0 && j+1 <= cols-1 && cells[i-1][j+1].getMined()) count++;                                          
                    if (j-1 >= 0 && cells[i][j-1].getMined()) count++;
                    if (j+1 <= cols-1 && cells[i][j+1].getMined()) count++;                                       
                    if (i+1 <= rows-1 && j-1 >= 0 && cells[i+1][j-1].getMined()) count++;
                    if (i+1 <= rows-1 && cells[i+1][j].getMined()) count++;
                    if (i+1 <= rows-1 && j+1 <= cols-1 && cells[i+1][j+1].getMined()) count++;
                    cells[i][j].setAdj(count);              
                    // cout << count; -- for testing purposes
            }
        } 
    }
}

void Board::print(){
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
                for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++){
                        cells[i][j].print();
                                        }
                cout << endl << endl;
        }
}

void Board::peek(){
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
                for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++){
                        cells[i][j].peek();
                }
                cout << endl << endl;
        }
}

// -------------------------
// main function for testing
// -------------------------

int main(void) {
    //Cell c;
    //c.unittest();
    srand(time(0));

    Board b;
    b.mixMined();
    b.adjacencycount();
    b.peek();

    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to get my cells to swap, so that the mines would randomize every new game. Ive searched around and couldn't find a solution to this. I added "==" but that function isn't going to do what i want it to.

++EDIT++ I'm sorry it did state lvalue required, i missed typed that

```
minesweeper.cpp: In member function ‘void Board::mixMined()’:
minesweeper.cpp:130: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
minesweeper.cpp:131: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
```

Thats the error that occurs.

Comment: What does getMinded return (exactly)?

Comment: Could you please post full code.

Comment: What is the signature of `getMined()`? It should be something like `bool& getMined()`. (Note the reference.)

Comment: I'll bet the error message says "lvalue required".

Comment: Could you please post the full compilation error message?

Answer (score 5):

I think `getMined()` is actually something like this:

`bool getMined()`

So you are trying to assign to `rValue` which is not possible

You might want to write some function like:

`void setMined(bool m)` and the use it like:

`cells[r1][c1].setMined( cells[r2][c2].getMined() );`